# Как использовать значение куки в gatling?

Tags: производительность, scala, gatling

Относительно недавно начал использовать Gatling для нагрузочного тестирования и все аспекты ещё не совсем понятны.
Сценарий тестирования включает в себя захват значение куки, которое может быть: 2, 4, 6.
Использовал следующее:

```
      http("Генерация юзера")
        .get("url")
        .check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", """status_id=(.*?);""").saveAs("status"))
```

Но в итоге получаю следующую ошибку:

```
headerRegex((Set-Cookie, status_id=(.*?);)).find.exists, found nothing
```

Всё делал по документации, но результата не добился, подскажите, как можно вытащить значение куки и использовать это значение в дальнейшем сценарии? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Трудно сказать что пошло не так, возможно сама регулярлка не правильная.
Вообще у Gatling есть более красивый способ достать значение куки

Вот как пример:

```
.exec(getCookieValue(CookieKey("status_id")))
```

Но надо быть аккуратным с тем какой домен у куки, стоит ли secure и т.д.
Поэтому можешь ознакомиться с офф докой- https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/helpers/#getting-cookie-value